# Avoid UI flicker/hangs when navigating through ActionBar tabs

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, freeze

I am working on an Android app that uses 5 ActionBar tabs to navigate between different pages/fragments.

**Problem is, that the navigation between the fragments is causing the UI to hang/flicker.**

The UI of the fragments is not dynamic, meaning that it is not build with a static set of controls. When a fragment becomes visible apps starts to load the corresponsing view model, e.g. by loading a set of data from a server. As soon as the model is loaded the UI is generated. Thus showing a fragment includes the following stepps:

1. Show an inderminante progress bar to indicate the running progress
2. Start an AsyncTask to do the heavy loading
3. As soon as the task is complete generate the UI, e.g. insert an ImageView for every loaded image.
4. Hide the progress bar and show the generated content.

I thought using a background thread to do the loading would avoid any UI hangs but this it not the case. The creation of the UI elements has to be done in the UI thread of course and it seems that this work is causing the UI hangs.

Even if the number of UI elements that have to be create is quite low (e.g. create 10 Buttons) the UI hangs for a moment. Thus using other strategies (e.g. create visible elements only) does not solve the problem.

Only when **no** UI elements are created at all the navigation between the fragments runs fluently.

**How can I solve this?**

The only solution I found so far is, not to load the view model / generate the UI when a fragment becomes visible / is created but as soon as the activity is created. In that case I would only show the activity once the view models / views of all fragments have been loaded/generated. But this would mean to load a lot of data without knowing if it will be used at all.

**Is there any better solution?** Creating UI elements on the fly is not that uncommon, is it? Thus there has to be a way how this can be done without blocking the UI.